# Voting an Answer-Under-Edit

Tags: support

Not being aware of the tech. behind ELU, I would like to ask:
If someone up/ down votes an answer unaware that it is being edited, will the edited answer miss the vote?
In other words, will Save-edit recognize the voting that takes place *during* the edit?

Comment: You mean, if you're editing, and I vote, will the vote still count?

Comment: Yes. You got it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Votes and post edits aren't connected to each other. If you are currently editing a post, and I vote, then my vote will still count. However, after five minutes votes are locked on a given edit of a post--so, if you edit again, I can change my vote.

Comment: Thanks. It must be that there was an up followed by a down vote (second thoughts) -- momentarily it was showing 160 before reverting to 150 again -- unrelated to edit.

Comment: @Kris I think you mean someone *unvoted*, not down-voted. You should be able to see that from your reputation stats.

Comment: I avoided saying 'unvoted' because I wasn't sure if the negative was by the same voter. I'll check repstats -- forgot how to get that tabular report of reputation changes.